# Convert list to array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

This function means to transforms a list to an array:

```
const list = {"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":null}};

function list_to_array(list) {
  arr = [];
  for (const property in list) {
    if (property == "value") {
      arr.push(property);
    } else if (property == "rest") {
      for (const property in rest) {
        arr.push(property);
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(list_to_array(x)));
```

but I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: rest is not defined`

How can I iterate in the rest object ? or how would you rewrite this function?

Comment: Your function never returns a value. Also to use the object's `rest` property you need to access it using the property accessor eg `list.rest`, `list['rest']`. `rest` on its own is going to try to look for a variable named `rest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a recursion here, if you the `property` is "rest". In addition to get the value use `list[property]`:

```js
function list_to_array(list) {
  const arr = [];
  
  for (const property in list) {
    if (property == "value") {
      arr.push(list[property]);
    } else if (property == "rest") {
      arr.push(...list_to_array(list[property])); // call list_to_array on the rest
    }
  }
  
  return arr; // return the arr
}

const list = {"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":null}};

const result = list_to_array(list);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

However, you can shorten the recursion - always add the value. If `rest` exists, return the call of the function with `rest` and the current `arr`. If no `rest`, return `arr`:

```js
function list_to_array({ value, rest } = {}, arr = []) {
  arr.push(value);
  return rest ? list_to_array(rest, arr) : arr;
}

const list = {"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":null}};

const result = list_to_array(list);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

A simpler solution would be to use a `while` loop, and take the `rest` property value on each iteration:

```js
function list_to_array(list) {
  const arr = [];
  let current = list;
  
  do {
    arr.push(current?.value);
  } while(current = current?.rest);
  
  return arr; // return the arr
}

const list = {"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":null}};

const result = list_to_array(list);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to avoid recursion here since with big lists that could overflow the stack easily. A simple `while` loop would do the task:

```js
function list_to_array(list) {
  const arr = [list.value];
  while(list = list.rest) arr.push(list.value);
  return arr;
}

const list = {"value":10,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":null}};

const result = list_to_array(list);

console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `x = array_to_list([10, 20]);` could be `x = list_to_array([10, 20]);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? It's unclear what you want to tell...